# calling Spring-WS service with dynamic url in the WSDL

Tags: spring, rest, spring-ws

I am working on Spring-WS which generates the WSDL based on the XSD created manually.

I am trying to expose Spring Controller RESTFul API services as the WSDL using Spring-WS.

Can any one suggest the solution on how to define the dynamic url using the spring web services for the existing RESTFul services in the WSDL using spring-ws?

e.g. if RESTFul API url is 
/localhost:8080/Apps/rest/Customer/**{customer-id}**/care

then how to pass the {customer-id} at the time of spring webservice call?
How to specify this url in the spring wsdl defination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST web services don't have WSDL. Spring-WS and WSDL are both for SOAP services.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for reply. So what will be the mechanism or way to define the dynammic url as I mentioned above?

Comment: Spring MVC request mappings are what you need for REST APIs. i.e. Something like: @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/Customer/{customerId}/care")